# Is the the difference $\mathbb {Q} - \mathbb {N}$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the the difference $\mathbb {Q} -  \mathbb {N}$ countable? I feel so, since $\mathbb {Q} -  \mathbb {N}$ has infinite cardinal,  $\mathbb {Q} -  \mathbb {N} \subset \mathbb {Q} \hspace{2mm}$ countable and the cardinal of natural numbers is the "smallest" infinity

Comment: It's a subset of a countable set, so....

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is countable, so any subset of it is

Comment: You can infact show that a subset of a countable infinite set is again countable.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathbb{Q} - \mathbb{N}$ is countable. Generally, any infinite subset of a countable set is countable.

If you are interested in a proof of this, I can add one.

Comment: It's okay, no problem. I've recently found a proof. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: Finite sets are countable too, usually.

Comment: @Arthur, "usually"?

Comment: I think what Arthur means (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the definition of a countable set usually includes finite sets. I'm using the definition in Baby Rudin myself, which makes a distinction between finite sets, countable sets, and "at most" (finite or countable) sets, so the proof I would give would not include finite sets.

Comment: For example, the definition of countable I am using is: a set $A$ is countable if there exists a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$. A definition that includes finite set would also include sets $A$ such that there exists a bijection $f: A \to I_n$ where $I_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. In this case, I suppose countable just means "not uncountable" or "lacking a cardinality larger than that of $\mathbb{N}$."